# How can I sum two numbers with decimals?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sum two numbers with decimals and this is my code:

```js
function myNumbers() {
   var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);  
   var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
   alert(val1+val2);
}
```

```html
value1 = <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1"/>
value2 = <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2"/>
<input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:myNumbers()"/>
```

Comment: Suren Srapyan solved my Q
parseInt gets the integer part of the number. Use parseFloat instead of it

Comment: what you want excellently ? adding two integer as well as floats or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont add `toFixed` with float the result of adding `0.1 + 0.2` will be `0.30000000000000004`

```js
function myNumbers() {
   var val1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);  
   var val2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value2").value);
   alert((val1+val2).toFixed(1));
}
```

```html
value1 = <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1"/>
value2 = <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2"/>
<input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:myNumbers()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt` will get a complete number. Use `parseFloat` instead, this will get number and their decimal values.

```js
function myNumbers() {
   var val1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);  
   var val2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value2").value);
   alert(val1+val2);
}
```

```html
value1 = <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1"/>
value2 = <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2"/>
<input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:myNumbers()"/>
```

Comment: @Suren I've always said that SO should force people to say _why_ they downvote. Just downvoting doesn't bring anything constructive. Being forced to give a reason can only help people know what they did wrong.

Comment: Yes I am about this. If anything is wrong he/she can write about it to let me know

Comment: I've no idea either,.. So I'm going to up-vote, to counter..  I normally wound't up vote this, as for me it's obvious anyway, but I certainly wound't down-vote.  Hope  you get more up-votes now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try **parseFloat()** instead **parseInt()** to convert it into float val